# the fastest way to Sum of many numbers java

Tags: java, performance, sum

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            int read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            if (read == 0) {
                break;
            }
            int sum;
            sum = read;
            System.out.println("Sum now: " + sum);
            while (true) {
                int read1 = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
                if (read1 != 0) {
                    sum += read1;

                    System.out.println("Sum now: " + sum);
                } else if (read1 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Sum in the end: " + sum);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is a code i wrote iwant to know if this is the fastest way to it?

Comment: if you know any better logic please let me know

Comment: In the while loop you have a read from standard input... so if you type very quickly it works :-D

Comment: You don't need this `elseif` `else if (read1 == 0) {` it can be `else ` itself

Comment: @soorapadman - What you say is true. However, this won't improve performance. 1) the JIT compiler's optimizer will probably optimize the redundant test away.  2) If it doesn't, the performance difference is too small to be relevant.  The **real** reason to make the change you (correctly) suggest is to improve readability.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the comment .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question here. You see, your code does:

- ask the user to put in a value (respectively to read from standard.in)
- to then accumulate these values
- and print them (multiple times)

Now:

- performance doesn't matter here **at all**
- if it would, the real bottle neck is reading from standard.in, and printing to standard.out

In short: you can't write "this" code much different, it is already "optimal" in the sense of: you get your input, you don't waste time/memory "storing" it, you simply accumulate the sum, done. *That* requirement is coded fine.

The only thing you could save would be your print statements, as a single println can costs you **milli**seconds, while adding int values probably happens in **nano**seconds. Yes: printing is thousands of times slower than adding up values. And worse: if there is a human being sitting in front of the machine, then the program sits there doing nothing until the user types a number and the ENTER key. Thus "how you add" doesn't affect the overall runtime of your code in any significant way.

In other words: you are at a point where worrying about "performance" is not helpful. Learn how to write human readable code, learn how to write simple code that elegantly does what you want to do.

Performance is a luxury problem that you worry about at later points of your learning curve.